# How to hide multiple elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, styles

Yes, the question has been asked so many times, but this one is a bit more specific. I need JavaScript code that shows/hides all elements of a certain `class`. The code must be compatible with the older browsers and Internet Explorer, and it must have an extremely small footprint. So, please don't post jQuery solutions, since this task will use 0.01% of the code from the library. So far I've come up with this:

```
var flip = document.getElementsByTagName(_tag);
if (trigger)
  for (var i = 0; i < flip.length; i++)
    if (flip[i].className == _class) flip[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    else
      for (var i = 0; i < flip.length; i++)
        if (flip[i].className == _class) flip[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Since `getElementsByclassName` does not work in IE, and most common solutions are too bulky for me. Is this code optimal for the task, or could it be streamlined even more? (as a reference, the previous solution used a `cgi` to add `<style>.myclass {visibility:visible}</class>` to the page)

Comment: you can use `.className` property to get the all classes name and  use `css.display='none' OR css.display=''` for hide/show oR YOU CAN use document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').

Comment: Why are your curly braces(`{`, `}`) missing?

Comment: @Prog: can you be little more specific about css.dsiplay, I didn't get that?
@chipChocolate.py: because it's a one-liner if trigger then loop, loop does a single if that does a single command
@Tyr: there's no inner loop - it's the same code under `if` and `else` the only difference is in the visibility.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'older browsers'? What's your minimum version of IE?

Comment: as low as possible (let's say 6), hence no `querySelectorAll` nor `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a shim or iterate through the dom and get elements with your class. See no other solutions.

Comment: To make this an answer you'd need to show *how*, as currently written this is, at best, a comment. And I'm well aware that you can't leave comments everywhere, yet. But please wait until you can, rather than adding noise.

Comment: Well, then my solution is already optimal. I just needed a second opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same iterator (var i) in an inner for loop because it collides with your current loop. Remove the second inner one and check if class x is set, then set your property, do a "continue" and vice versa:

```
var flip = document.getElementsByTagName(_tag);
if (trigger) {
  for (var i = 0; i < flip.length; i++) {
    var state = flip[i].style.visibility;
    if (flip[i].className == _class && state == 'hidden') {
      flip[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
      continue;
    }

    if (flip[i].className == _class && state == 'visible') {
      flip[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very useful if you don't know the state of the element (but I do, so it's unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mockup of a classname-switcher, would that be an idea? If you use IE < 8, use `document.getElementsByTagName` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggledivshidden);
  
  function toggledivshidden() {
    return toggle('div', 'hidden');
  }

  function toggle(tag, clssname) {
    var flips = document.querySelectorAll(tag);
    for (var i = 0; i< flips.length; i+=1) {
      var classExists = RegExp(clssname, 'i').test(flips[i].className);
      classEdit(flips[i], clssname, classExists);
    }
  }
  
  // add or remove a classname, without destroying other classnames 
  function classEdit(el, clname, remove) {
    var re = RegExp(clname, 'g'),
        current = el.className;
    el.className = ( remove ? current.replace(re, '')
                            : re.test(current)
                             ? current
                             : current +' '+clname )
                   .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')     // remove redundant spaces
                   .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,''); // trim
    
    return true;
  }
}())
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
  height: 0;
}

div:after {
  content: ' - className: "'attr(class)'"';
  color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden some">originally hidden</div>
<div class="some hidden foo bar">originally hidden</div>
<div class="some more etc">originally visible</div>
<div class="some">originally visible</div>


<button>toggle</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

I agree with Luba, here's a shim: [getElementsByClassName.polyfill.js](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607)

As commented by Hemang, link only answers are invalid due to link change so here's the code from the link. The link is a shim for the deficit of getElementsByClassName in pre-ie9. Initially the shim tests the lack of getElementsByClassName then tests for  the presence of querySelectorAll, if this is not available (i.e. pre-ie8) then evaluate is used.

```
// Add a getElementsByClassName function if the browser doesn't have one
// Limitation: only works with one class name
// Copyright: Eike Send http://eike.se/nd
// License: MIT License

if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```